# visual studio, error in creating x64 dll and using in c# console app

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2019

I have successfully created a x86 dll project and referenced that in a c# console app (visual studio 2019). However, when I compile the dll project to a x64 target and try to add the output dll to the "add project reference" window in the console app it gives "The reference is invalid or unsupported" error. I have changed the following settings in the console app but it does not work:

Project properties->Build->platform target  to x64

configuration manager->active solution platform to x64 (using New)

anyone knows what the problem is?

Comment: Normally, you don't reference native libraries directly. Instead, you use a `DllImportAttribute` to reference library functions. How is your existing project referencing the library?

Comment: why don't you just import the dll project to the solution of the console app and reference the project directly?

Comment: @thomas-klammer  I tried, but when I built the dll project inside the console project, the dll output did not generated.

Comment: @pmf: I used "Project->add project reference" to "import" the library. Giving up using that option and using the absolute dll path at "DllImport()" solved my problem.